Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Failed to find Build Tools revision 33.0.1
After updating Flutter, I encountered an error while building the app:

Failed to find Build Tools revision 33.0.1
I tried running common troubleshooting commands like flutter clean and flutter pub get, but the issue persisted. I also checked the SDK Manager in Android Studio to ensure that API 33 (Android 13) was installed. However, despite confirming that the necessary SDK components were present, the build still failed with the same error.

This error usually occurs because the specific version of the Android Build Tools, in this case, version 33.0.1, is missing or not properly installed. The SDK might have the API 33 installed but lacks the correct build tools version required to compile the app....
